# jQuery validation - int field validation sometimes doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, ckeditor

On my website, I have a form that includes CKEditor, and input field for numeric value. Now, sometimes, when I try to submit form, validator is saying, that numeric input field is not in a proper range. The problem is, that the range is set to 1-1000, and I am setting the value that is within this range. So it is totally ignoring my input and assuming that there is nothing. The main problem with that behavior is, that most of the times this works okay (I mean it is validating correctly). But like 10% of the times, it is doing those weird things, and console is throwing no errors... Has anyone had similar problems?

Is it maybe possible to turn off jquery validation for single input field?

Edit: here is my input field:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Price must be a number." data-val-range="The field Price must be between 1 and 1000." data-val-range-max="1000" data-val-range-min="1" data-val-required="The Price field is required." id="Price" name="Price" type="number" value="0">
```

Comment: Hard to know. Do you have any examples of the jquery part?

Comment: How are you attaching the validation?

Comment: @nick: this is the main problem. I cannot provide anything since I don't know exactly where is the problem. I have no idea how to debug this, since it happens only sometimes.

Comment: @TravisJ: I don't fully understand. I am just including javascript files, that's all. Also I updated my post with some code.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is how to data is being evaluated. If javascript thinks it's a string, it could be doing something like ("2" > "10") true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an mvc input to me. I would assume you are using this somewhere: `@Html.ValidationFor( m => m.Price )` which you may omit if you wish to remove validation altogether.

If that is not the case, then just remove the data-annotations from the element

```
<input id="Price" name="Price" value="0" />
```

However, I think you should also consider allowing the range to be 0-100 *or* setting the initial value at `1`. The reason being that as it stands now if someone clicks submit without making an entry, then the value of the field will be `0`, and that will fail the range validation of `1-100`.

Comment: First of all, yes, this is MVC generated input. Also, I need it to be at least 1, so basically that validation rule is ok. Also, this problem is somewhat related to CKEditor. I know this, because I have similar form (with CKE) somewhere else, and I have a rule that should allow 0-1000 values. And there is the same error, even if nothing is specified inside.